# Can I set up a Symfony2 ORM inheritance relationship using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony, inheritance, orm, relationship

I have one table `tech_note` and I would like to have 3 tables more `tech_note_es`, `tech_note_en` and `tech_note_fr` (in a future many more tables). And the `tech_note` can be in the 3 tables at same time.

My idea is attach to `tech_note_en` and automatically receive attributes from `tech_note`.

**SECOND EDIT:**

I would like somthing like that: I search in `Tech_note_EN by ID=3` (I recive fields from `tech_note_EN with ID=3` and fields `tech_note with ID=3`.

But if I search in `Tech_note_ES BY ID=3` (I recive fields from `tech_note_ES with ID=3` and tech_note fields from `tech_note with ID=3` (**the same fields from above**)

The tech_note have a ID=3. Tech_note_EN have ID=3, and Tech_note_ES have ID=3

**EDIT WITH NEW CLASSES**:

Now I have this error:
Entity 'EVTS\FrontendBundle\Entity\Tech_note_en' has a composite identifier but uses an ID generator other than manually assigning (Identity, Sequence). This is not supported.

**TECH_NOTE**

```
abstract class Tech_note {

        /**
         * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;


    /**
     * @var datetime $control_date
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="control_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $control_date;

    /**
     * @var string $comment
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="string")
     */
    private $comment;
```

---

**TECH_NOTE_EN**

```
class Tech_note_en extends Tech_note {


    /**
     * @var integer $tech_note_id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="tech_note_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="tech_note")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tech_note_id",referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tech_note_id;    

    /**
     * @var text $symptom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="symptom", type="text")
     */
    private $symptom;

    /**
     * @var text $cause
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cause", type="text")
     */
    private $cause;

    /**
     * @var string $solution
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="solution", type="string")
     */
    private $solution;
```

---

---

**OLD CLASSES**

**TECH_NOTE**

```
class Tech_note {

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;


    /**
     * @var datetime $control_date
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="control_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $control_date;

    /**
     * @var string $comment
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="string")
     */
    private $comment;
```

---

**TECH_NOTE_EN**

```
class Tech_note_en
{
    /**
     * @var integer $tech_note_id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="tech_note_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="tech_note")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tech_note_id",referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tech_note_id;    

    /**
     * @var text $symptom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="symptom", type="text")
     */
    private $symptom;

    /**
     * @var text $cause
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cause", type="text")
     */
    private $cause;

    /**
     * @var string $solution
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="solution", type="string")
     */
    private $solution;
```

Comment: Could you please specify where do you find difficulties or what it's the expected answer ?

Comment: One table per language feels wrong - you should not need to modify the database structure to add a new language. Can you use two related tables instead: `tech_note` and `tech_note_lang`? I don't think you need inheritance here, either.

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome solution to your problem, which is [single table inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)

What this does is basically Have one central table with general fields, and links to other table with specific fields.
In your case I would use this architectural model:
**abstract class TechNote** (abstract common entity, which contains common fields)
**class TechNoteEn extends TechNote** (specific entity which inherits common fields and adds specific EN fields)
and so on.
I find this as the best architectural solution for your problem.

Comment: If you need help in setting up your single table inheritance, let me know :)

Comment: TY for the answer, but now I have problems with the ID (the symfony error is: Entity 'EVTS\FrontendBundle\Entity\Tech_note_es' has a composite identifier but uses an ID generator other than manually assigning (Identity, Sequence). This is not supported.

Comment: You already have the id from the abstract. Remove it from the concrete entities. A.k.a. remove field $id from TechNoteEs :)

Comment: But if I done that, I can't do this: $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Tech_note_en')->find($ntec_id); I'm wrong?

Comment: Of course you can :) all your languages will have different ids, for example if you have ES and IT, first ES lang will have id 1, first IT will have id 2 :) they all have unique ids

Comment: But, in my project, the same tech_note exist in FR, EN, ES (at the same time). If I search by ID=3 in tech_note_ES I have the tech_note table with ID=3, and if I search by ID=" in tech_note_EN I would have the same fields becouse are the same (I'm editting my original post)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75920/discussion-between-roger-guasch-and-pcm).

Answer (score 0):

That's your ORM's job.

```
// Assuming $tech_note_en is a Tech_note_en instance
$tech_note_en->getTechNote();
```

(something like this ^^)